# Android AdMob implementation/when does the ads show up?

Tags: android, admob

I've been searching through StackOverflow and I'm wondering about some things regarding AdMob. I'm done developing my app and have decided to make one free application and one non-free. The free one should have AdMob like a banner on it with ads of course.

Now I did, as everyone, the mistake with not putting target to sdk 14 or something and then I saw the banner space with a error message but now when I fixed it I did a fake android application on AdMob but nothing shows, even after I placed the ad - id number there.

I'm actually wondering, when does the ads show up on my application? Does a advertiser choose just my app to show ads on? Can't I have like always ads but I only get money when someone presses them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll know if you implemented the ads correctly by setting your test device and requesting a test ad.  The test ad should come back every time, assuming your publisher id is valid.

It takes a few days and multiple requests for the new id to start delivering real impressions.  The advertiser does not choose your app specifically; the AdMob network takes care of matching the advertiser's ad to the publisher's app.